# How to filter out an element from an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

What am I missing here? There's an 'id' matching the condition but it still filters an array which is the same as the previous one, without removing that specific 'id'. Fan thing, if I remove the not operator it filters the only item ('id') matching the condition. Is filter working differently with not operators? I uploaded a screenshot of the console just to make it clear.

```js
let removeFromLocalStorage = (id) =>{
    console.log(id);
    let items = accessItem();
    console.log(items);
    items = items.filter((item) =>{
        if(item.ids !== id){
            return item
        }      
    })
    console.log(items);
    localStorage.setItem('list', JSON.stringify(items));
    
}
```

[image: Console Logs]

Comment: Your filter callback should return `true` (or a truthy value) when you want to keep the value, and `false` (or a falsy value) when you don't want to keep the value.

Comment: Simply `return item.ids !== id` e.g. `items = items.filter(item => item.ids !== id)`

Comment: try `return true`

Answer (score -1):

From the filter method documentation available [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp):
`The filter() method creates an array filled with all array elements that pass a test`

You should only return the case you want to test, in your example:

```
items = items.filter((item) => item.ids !== id)
```